# Toggling a property with jquery

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

Trying to make a simple toggle button.

To explain it:

> Input has a property of disabled
>
> User presses button disabled becomes false
>
> User presses Save Changes and button becomes disabled again.

Here's my code

```
$('#password').click(function(){
    if($("#password") === "disabled"){
        $("#password").prop("disabled", false);
    } else if ($("#password").prop("disabled", false)){
        $("#password").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Sidenote: I'm using bootstrap

Comment: one possible example could be: `<input type="password" disabled="true"/>
<button onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].disabled=false">Enable</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].disabled=true">Save</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Disabled form elements don't trigger any mouse events, your event handler function will never be called. Even if it was..
- A jQuery collection (`$("#password")`) will never be equal to the string literal `"disabled"`, although it's a truthy value, you've used `===`. Regardless, I'm pretty sure you are looking for

  ```
  if( $('#password').prop('disabled') ) {
  ```
- The setter version of `.prop()` returns the original collection, so will always be a truthy value.

To have the `<input>` enabled by default and have it disabled when your form is submitted (assuming you are using a form..):

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    $('#password').prop('disabled', true); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try like;

$('#password').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':disabled')){
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    } 
    else {
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like;

```
> $('#password').click(function(){
>     if($(this).is(':disabled')){
>         $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
>     } 
>     else {
>         $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
>     } });
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I fixed it for any future reference.

This is when the button's id = "#password-button" and the input id="password"

```
       $(function() {
            $('#password-button').click(function() {
                if ($("#password").prop("disabled")) {
                    $("#password").prop("disabled", false);
                } else {
                    $("#password").prop("disabled", true);
                }
            });
        });
```